# How to return the index of certain duplicate strings in a character vector ignoring the index of the first occurence of the duplicate string?

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings and I want to return the index of the duplicate values, except for the index of the first occurrence of a duplicate value, given another vector with matches. For example:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c")
matching_values <- c("a", "b")
```

So I would like to have an integer vector returned with the indexes 4, 5, 6. So the first duplicate of `a` occurs at position 5 and the second duplicate at position 6. The first duplicate for `b` occurs at index 4 and because I did not specify to match `c`, there will be no index returned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
which(duplicated(x) & x %in% matching_values)
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `duplicated` with `%in%`

```
which(x %in% matching_values & duplicated(x))
#[1] 4 5 6
```